# How do I show an image in a table cell given its URL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

This code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"recipes"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"time"];
```

shows the title and subtitle of the cell, and takes data from JSON file.

This code:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
```

shows the same static image to all the cells in the table view. How can I make this line of code something like the first two ones, so it will grab the image link from the JSON file and display the image as thumbnail?

Comment: Did you solve your problem, or do you need something more?

Comment: I didn't solve my problem, nobody is giving me a useful answer.

Comment: Did you try using SDWebImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the image first.

This question has been asked about a thousand times here:

[Set UIImageView image using a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962561/set-uiimageview-image-using-a-url)

[Easy Asynchronous Image Download UIImage View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616327/easy-asynchronous-image-download-uiimage-view)

[Download Images, Display Them in UIImageView, and SORT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238470/download-images-display-them-in-uiimageview-and-sort)

[iPhone SDK: Download and Set UIImageView before first view controller is displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402669/iphone-sdk-download-and-set-uiimageview-before-first-view-controller-is-display)

Answer (score 0):

```
  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"URLOfYourImage"]]]
```

Comment: This will freeze the main thread. Don't know if that's what they were going for.

Comment: I know but it was a question about a single line of code: "How can I make this line of code something like the first two ones, so it will grab the image link from the JSON file and display the image as thumbnail?"

Comment: @Ivon If he had asked "How can I quickly remove my own foot?" you wouldn't say, "Grab a hatchet." You'd advise him to find a better solution to the real problem at hand, like therapy.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [this category](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h) you can then do it with one line of code.

```
[cell.imageViewPhoto setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.so.com/image.png"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.gif"]];
```

Moreover this category offers you lazy loading and caching capabilities which I think is important for what you need. I use it a lot in my projects.